# Pointer as declaration of a function?

Tags: c, pointers

First I have the declaration

```
char (*x)(int field);
char yes_or_no(int);
char yes_or_no(int field)
{
    if(field==1)
    return 'y';
    else
    return 'n';
}

x=&yes_or_no;

printf("Now we can call this function by using the pointer *x by using (*x)(1),\nwhich gives us: \n'%c'\n", (*x)(1));
```

This works properly, but now I have to do something with

```
char *y(int field);
```

Which is or could be a declaration of a function? How could I do 'something' with this last statement/declaration?

Kind regards.

Comment: `char * y(int field)` is declaration of function not could be.. mind it

Comment: `char *y(int field);` is a declaration of a function that *returns* a pointer to `char` (and takes a single `int` parameter).

Comment: So what you want with this please elaborate a little

Comment: `x=yes_or_no;` also will works. `x=&yes_or_no;` is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char (*x)(int field);
```

declares a function variable `x`, returning `char`.

```
char * y(int field);
```

declares a function `y()` returning `char *`.

Mind the missing pair of brackets `()` in the second declaration.

A function variable for the seocnd case would be declared:

```
char * (*yvar)(int field);
```

Comment: The common terminology is function pointer, not variable since variable is a container of value itself. Where as pointer is the container of only address and makes sense in case of functions since it only contains the starting address of the piece of code for function. +1 otherwise

Comment: You are right, I am inaccurate here. Anyhow I feel the term "*variable*" makes sense for understanding. So I'd propose "*function pointer variable*" as reasonable compromise. @fayyazkl

Answer (score 0):

The function pointer would have type:

```
char *(*x) (int);
```

The declaration:

```
char *y(int field);
```

Note that the unary operator `&` is not required to have the address of a function. Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char *(*x) (int);
const char *yes_or_no(int field);

const char *yes_or_no(int field)
{
    if (field == 1)
        return "y";
    else
        return "n";
}

int main(void)
{
    x = yes_or_no;
    printf("'%s'\n", x(1));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should mention that char *y(int field); is actually a function named y returning a char *. It is not a function pointer. The () make all the difference.